# How to handle crashes on save causing "Project file read error: unexpected end of file at line 1 column 1 for file [pathway]"?

Tags: qgis

QGIS 1.8.0

Tried to save a project and as I saved it gave me the "QGIS has experienced an error and needs to close"
Next time I went to open the project I got this (well I was going to post an image of the error but apparently I need a "10 reputation" to do that) suffice to say it says:

"Project file read error: unexpected end of file at line 1 column 1 for file [pathway]"

The project file now says 0KB for the file size.  Any idea how to get my project restored?  Why are the crashes happening?

QGIS has been crashing more and more frequently especially when saving, trying to split features, and when opening the print composer.  No error messages other than the generic "QGIS has encountered and error and needs to close."

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows XP, Service Pack 3

Comment: Not an answer, but I've just had the exact same thing happen with Mac OS X 10.7.5 and Dufour 2.0.1. Hope I can find an answer somewhere ...

Comment: the same has just happened to me!!! and I can´t access to a backup for other reasons. I'm desperated!! please help

Comment: @luz (and Karl) this kind of error has a better chance of being answered on QGIS mailing list or irc. See http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/support.html

Answer (score 3):

Open your your-project-name.qgs~ file in any text editor software, for my case I used Adobe Dreamweaver. Save that file as your-project-name.qgs (Note that I removed the ~ at the end) overwritting the excisting one. Save and re-open the project.